# what is FSUM7351 not found in Linux

Tags: linux

When I tried to run a java  by

../jre/bin abc.java

I am getting this: FSUM7351 not found

What it means?

Answer (score 0):

In a standard JRE installation jre/bin is a directory. To run a Java program you need to use [javac](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/javac/) to build a class file, then run it with [java](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/java/). Something like:

```
../jre/bin/javac abc.java
../jre/bin/java -classpath . abc
```

As a side note, as stated [here](http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/BOOKS/bpxza8a0/1.2.8.1339) FSUM7351 is an IBM [OS/390](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/OS/390) error, not a GNU/Linux error.